# How does work function transform in Einstein's special theory of relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, condensed-matter, reference-frames, material-science

A photon with energy greater than the [work function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function) hits the metal, and an electron is knocked off.

Now, suppose we were in an inertial frame moving with a velocity $v$ with respect to the metal such that the photon is red-shifted to have an energy less than the work function. Will we observe the electron being knocked off now?

The knocking off of an electron is a physical phenomenon and must occur in all frames, if in one.

Comment: In the movie frame, the metal is moving, and the minimum energy of the photon to knock off an electron is then obviously different, so that the condition is equivalent in all frames. The minimum energy to knock off an electron is normally specified in the metal's rest frame.

Comment: @LubošMotl I figured that much, but how does that energy transform? The idea of a bounded electron is part quantum mechanical, and that makes me unsure of how plain old special relativity be applied there.

Comment: Plain and old special relativity holds anywhere and everywhere and always (at least if GR is not needed - if the gravity is weak or otherwise easily incorporated). The laws have the simple form in all reference frames. Just the laws describing the properties of materials, including ionization, are simpler in the rest frame of the material. But in each frame, you may simply say that the law is "whatever you get by Lorentz-transforming the laws in the rest frame into our frame".

Answer (score 1):

> How does work function transform in Einstein's special theory of relativity?

The [work function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function) of (some particular spot on the surface of) some particular piece of metal is not subject to transformation at all;
instead it is a proper attribute of this piece of metal under consideration;    it remains **invariant** under any (change of) description.

> A photon with energy greater than the work function hits the metal, and an electron is knocked off.

Likewise, the energy of a particular photon with respect to the particular piece of metal under consideration (necessarily, before the electron was knocked off and the remaining piece of metal might have picked up some momentum with respect to the (inertial) reference system to which it had belonged initially) is an **invariant**;
its value is independent of the choice of (inertial) reference system with respect to which the photon and the piece of metal might be described.

> Now, suppose we were in an inertial frame moving with a velocity v with respect to the metal such that the photon is red-shifted to have an energy less than the work function.

The photon would consequently be (described as) red-shifted with respect to (the members of) this additionally introduced inertial frame;
but of course **not** with respect to the piece of metal under consideration.

The energy of this photon **with respect to** (members of) this additionally introduced inertial frame would be lower by a factor $$\sqrt{\frac{1 - \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}{1 + \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$$ compared to the energy of this photon **with respect to** the piece of metal.
(It's just improper to attribute a value of energy e.g. to a photon without specifying **with respect to** which (suitable) reference system the energy is meant to be evaluated.)